# final performance veredict given different testing procedures

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, meta-analysis

I have K time series of a certain performance indicator each for a 5-day "reference" period and a 5-day "measurement" period with equal frequencies. The goal is to give a verdict if the performance in the measurement priod is changed compared to the reference period.

I have approached the problem in two different ways. Once, I do a time series analysis where given the reference period, I predict the measurement period. Comparing the predicted measurement (together with its confidence bounds) and actuall measurement time series, I use a tracking signal algorithm to identify if a change exists or not. As an alternative method, I aggregate the daily time series to obtain a reference and a measurement dataset, each with 5 samples (corresponding to 5 days). Then, assuming that the aggregated samples are independent, I use a non-parametric statistical testing to identify if the performance is changed or not.

Using each of the methods, I get a "change" or "no change" for the K time series that might even be contradicting. For example, time series approach might detect a change for the k:th time series while the statistical test might not. Now, I have K verdicts using the timeseries solution and K verdicts using the statistical testing solution. It might be possible to use a p-value combiner to come up with a single p-value using the statistical testing approach.

I am wondering  if there is a way to combine the K timeseries estimates? Or if there is a way to "fuse" these two sets of results (K for timeseries and K for statistical testing) together and give a final verdict.